# Can we keep the Form scrollbar but prevent the form from auto-scrolling to the focused control?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, scrollbar, autoscroll

I want to prevent my form from automatically scrolling when a control at the bottom is focused but still keep the scrollbars if they ever appear.

Since some users have a slightly lower screen's resolution than the form, the scrollbars do sometimes appear. This created a problem with some DataGridView. Since the `AutoScroll` option is enabled, when clicking the DataGridView, it does a multiselect since we click and it moves.

When I disable the `AutoScroll` property, the scrollbars go away. Therefore, the user can't see everything.

Is there a way to disable the `AutoScroll`, but still keep the scrollbar?

Comment: Ok so you want to disable the autoscroll, but still keep it visibly on the screen? Does that mean you still want users to use it or no? Doesn't make much sense to me, just leave them on the screen so a user can use them if needed, if it's causing an issue with some code you have, refactor the code that is the issue. The scrollbars are there for a reason, to aid in seeing other objects when needed.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ My problem is not with my code, but with the "Autoscroll" itself. When the user click on a DGV that is lower in the screen, the form will automatically scroll to the position. Which is why i'm trying to disable the autoscroll. Doing so, it disable the scrollbar the user cant recenter the screen if he want's to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, you basically want the user to have the ability to scroll the form *manually* but prevent the form from scrolling automatically to the control that gets focused.

Put this code in your form:

```
Protected Overrides Function ScrollToControl(activeControl As Control) As Point
    'Return MyBase.ScrollToControl(activeControl)   ' <-- Keep this line commented.
End Function
```

### Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: I looked for this once. I'm taking notes.